Listings hook to detect whether the current line contains a colon?
TL;DR: I want to use the listings package for typesetting YAML snippets. For example:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=yaml]
key: value
list:
  - value1
  - value2
env:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
\end{lstlisting}

I came up with an almost-working style, but I have a specific issue with styling YAML keys, namely before the :, while \lstdefinelanguage | moredelim's feature especially works to style the sequel of the delimiter.
Minimal complete example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\YAMLcolonstyle}{\color{red}}
\newcommand{\YAMLkeystyle}{\color{purple}}
\newcommand{\YAMLnormalstyle}{\color{black}}
\lstdefinelanguage{yaml}{%
  moredelim=**[il][\YAMLcolonstyle{:}\YAMLnormalstyle]{:},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
% Aim: Switch to \YAMLkeystyle at beginning of line if it contains a :

% First approximation: Switch to \YAMLkeystyle unconditionally for yaml listings
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\YAMLlang}{yaml}
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\ifx\lst@language\YAMLlang\YAMLkeystyle\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=yaml]
key: value
list:
  - value1
  - value2
env:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

Actual result

Expected result
I would like to style value1, value2 in black, like value3, value4.
Or in other words, trigger the \YAMLkeystyle in the hook only if the whole line contains some :.
Further search
Skimming the sources, it seemed \the\lst@token could be useful, but unfortunately it's only the first token of the line:
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\ifx\lst@language\YAMLlang
    \typeout{\the\lst@token}
  \fi}

yields
key1
list
\lst@nolig \lst@um- 
\lst@nolig \lst@um- 
key2
key3
key4

Maybe, \lst@Delay and \lst@IfSubstring could be useful, but I wasn't able to conclude this way.

but presumably not colons in strings eg - "value1 with a :"  would be black?

For a full-blown YAML style, yes this could be nice :) But for my question (for the examples I want to typeset), let's just assume that strings have no colon.
